# PayPal ignoring return url if it includes parameters

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating a paypal donation transaction. Everything else is working fine except I can't get the return url to have parameters:

```
return=http://example.com
```

works fine, however:

```
return=http://example.com?action_upon_return=complete
```

is just plain ignored and instead defaults to the PayPal page.

The PayPal documentation clearly says you can:

> If you want to pass your own custom parameters with a querystring, such as return=http://yoursite.com/somescript.php?name=value, please note that PayPal will generate HTML forms prompting the buyer to click a Submit button in order to go to your success page.

And [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#overriding-the-return-url-on-individual-transactions):

> For example, you might want to redirect payers to a URL on your site that is specific to that person, perhaps with a session-id or other transaction-related data included in the URL.

However I just can't get it to work.

I have tried all three of the `rm` settings, it doesn't change a thing.

I have tried it with Auto Return on and off.

Is this feature now broken or is there something I am missing?

Comment: and what about this: `return=http://example.com/?action_upon_return=complete`. I mean, try to add `/` after your domain name

Comment: have you tried `return=http://example.com/index.html?action_upon_return=complete` i.e. including the file?

Comment: just tried those @devsie and no luck, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have never really tried passing parameters with the return URL.

One way that you could do it:

- Create a session variable along the lines of "complete"
- Check to see if session variable exists/what it contains and then do something.

You could do a few different things with it though. If you are checking to simply see if they have completed the donation so that you can display a completed/thank you page, then you could simply check if that session variable exists.

So on the return page, check if the session variable is set. If it is set, do something. If the user ever navigates back to the return page, it will still display the thank you information (assuming the session variable is still set). Remember to unset this session variable at the beginning of the donation process so that it won't be an issue if they attempt to donate again.

```
<?php

session_start();

//Set this once the transaction/donation is completed.
$_SESSION['complete'] = "something"; //Transaction ID/True/Some other data.

//This would be on the return page.
//Check if it is set, or the value of the variable depending on your needs.

if (isset($_SESSION['complete'])){
    echo "Thank you";

    //If you still have the transaction variables set, 
    //this is where you could use it to display something.

} 



?>
```

I personally have a simple confirmed page on payments that displays only the transaction ID. Since I unset my session transaction variables once I am done with them (put them in the database), my complete variable could hold the transaction ID. If it is set, display the page. If not, they haven't completed any transaction and we can redirect them or display something specific.